# I m working usecontext hook in next js and getting this error

Tags: next.js

[image]

getting this error when using use context and i dont know how to solve it
please help in solving this error im using next js

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include code and errors as text and not as an image.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. This error usually happens when you don't wrap the component that's using the context with the context provider.